# Order of dropping tablespaces for tables and indexes in Oracle

Tags: oracle, storage

I have an Oracle table that is in it's own tablespace. It has a spatial index in another tablespace and a normal index in another. If I want to drop them all. Does it matter what order I proceed in?

Comment: Indexes are optional structures, thus associated with a table, so dropping a table would anyway drop the index structure as well. See my answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the table. The indexes will be dropped along with the table.

Answer (score 0):

**Indexes** are optional structures **associated** with tables and clusters. If you drop the table, the associated indexes are also dropped.

To answer your confusion about different **tablespaces**, there is a reason to create in different tablespace or within same tablespace as that of the table. Keeping them in same tablespace makes it easy for database maintenance, however, keeping in different tablespaces is better in terms of performance.

From documentation -

> Indexes can be created in any tablespace. An index can be created in
>   the same or different tablespace as the table it indexes. If you use
>   the same tablespace for a table and its index, it can be more
>   convenient to perform database maintenance (such as tablespace or file
>   backup) or to ensure application availability. All the related data is
>   always online together.
>
> Using different tablespaces (on different disks) for a table and its
>   index produces better performance than storing the table and index in
>   the same tablespace. Disk contention is reduced. But, if you use
>   different tablespaces for a table and its index and one tablespace is
>   offline (containing either data or index), then the statements
>   referencing that table are not guaranteed to work.